# linux-crashdump configuration for large memory size

Tags: kernel, ram, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to setup linux-crashdump on a few hosts running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and 16.04.5 LTS.
The servers run at 128Gb of RAM. The application running on the servers (KVM guest with proprietary linux based OS) allocates about 96Gb of memory.
I tried reserving 128M, 512M, 4096M for crash but the kernel load process after "echo c > /proc/sysrg-trigger" runs out of memory and hangs.
Is it possible to configure reasonable RAM reserved for crash so that it worked?
This is needed to investigate kernel panic appearing regularly on host OS (Ubuntu)
Just some more details. I tried a lot of Ubuntu 14/16 versions. The kdump tools do not work. The kernel ran by kexec just runs out of memory and hangs. No matter how much memory is reserved - I tried 64, 128, 768 mb.